Embedding contragradient of Hecke algebra into smooth functions on group
Let $G$ be a unimodular locally profinite group (locally compact t.d.). The Hecke algebra $H(G)$ is the convolution algebra of locally constant, compactly supported distributions on $G$ and $C^\infty (G)$ the convolution algebra of locally constant functions $G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. These are both $G \times G$ modules by left and right translation. We denote by $\tilde{H(G)}$ the contragradient (smooth dual) of $H(G)$.
Is there a canonic embedding $\tilde{H(G)} \hookrightarrow  C^\infty (G)$ of $G \times G$ modules?
It might be helpful to note $H(G) \simeq C^\infty _c (G)$ where $C^\infty _c (G)$ is the algebra of compactly supported locally constant function $G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. This isomorphism is given by the Haar measure on $G$.

Motivation:
The Bernstein notes p.24 (proof of Lemma 10) contains the following:
$$
Hom_{G \times G}(\tilde{W} \otimes W, \tilde{H(G)}) \subset Hom_{G \times G}(\tilde{W} \otimes W, C^\infty (G)).
$$
where $W$ is a smooth irreducible compact representation.
(Verbatim the notes give
\begin{align}
Hom_{G \times G}(\tilde{W} \otimes W, \tilde{H(G)}) &\subset Hom_{G \times G}(\tilde{W} \otimes W, C^\infty (G \times G / \text{diagonal})) \\ &= Hom_{G \times G}(\tilde{W} \otimes W, C^\infty (G)) \\ &= Hom_{G \times G}(\tilde{W} \otimes W, Ind_G^{G \times G} \mathbb{C}_\text{triv})
\end{align}
but the RHS of lines 1 and 4 are canonically equal so I have reordered the equations, hopefully as Bernstein intended.)
